# Get object size from File

Tags: apache-spark, spark-avro

I have an avro file outputted from a spark job with some objects in it:

```
Objavro.schema�{"type":"record","name":"topLevelRecord","fields": 
[{"name":"Name","type":["String","null"]},{"name":"Age","type": 
["int","null"]}]}
```

Is there a way to get specific size of an object?

Comment: Hi. Can you clarify what you mean by "size"? Do you mean the sum of the sizes of all the values in a row, as encoded in the Avro (i.e. a few bytes to store the `Age` integer, plus however many bytes it takes to store the `Name` string)? These values may be compressed, and there will be some overhead, so it's not entirely clear what the true size is. What is it you are trying to achieve here?

Comment: I am trying to find out value for only {"name":"Name","type":["String","null"]
@DNA

Comment: I can probably get the row size but I am trying to get each column size for that row.
Hope this is clear